# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages with laragon server

Tags: php, laravel, laragon

I have installed [bagisto](https://bagisto.com/en/), When I try to use command `composer install` or `composer update` a problem occurs:

> The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.

I use laragon as a server , and this is a 3 lines in `php.ini` in php folder

```
;extension=php_gmp.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
```

How could this error be resolved?

Comment: Intl is an optional extension that is (assuming it is actually installed) part of the PHP installation itself. It looks as though Laragon has some UI stuff in it menu for enabling and disabling PHP extensions, based on a quick Google and looking at some Laragon forum posts. If the option isn't there, it looks like you'll need to download the binary yourself. https://forum.laragon.org/topic/104/tutorial-how-to-add-php-extensions-to-laragon-ex-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: thanks i have solved the problem , it was with php path in environment variables , it looked at another server (xammp) , and i tried to enable intel extension in laragon server @Alex